# Too much time needed for transliteration

Tags: python, transliteration

I have tried using google_translate.transliterate and it works great for a small amount of data But I need to process huge data and it's taking a lot of time to transliterate. around 4000 records take 20 minutes!

**Is there any other library or an efficient way to do the transliteration task?**

My code:

```
def transliterate_and_remove_accent(text):
    
    try:
        transliterate_word =  google_translate.transliterate(text,'en')
        transliterate_word = transliterate_word.result
        transliterate_word = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', transliterate_word)
        transliterate_word = transliterate_word.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        transliterate_word = transliterate_word.decode("utf-8")
        source_language    =  google_translate.language(text).result.name

        return transliterate_word.title(),source_language

    except UnknownLanguage as err:
        return 'Transaction Failed'
    except TranslatepyException:
        return 'Transaction Failed'
    except Exception as e:
        return 'Transaction Failed'

# Call the Transliterating function and adding other required columns 

def transliterate(df):

    df['transliterate_and_source_data'] = df['company_name_org'].apply(lambda x: transliterate_and_remove_accent(x))
    df = df[df.transliterate_and_source_data != 'translation failed']
    df['transliterated_data']                 =  df['transliterate_and_source_data'].str[0]
    df['source_language']
```

Comment: Which part is slower? The call to `transliterate` or the various `normalize`, `encode`, `decode`? Or populating the dataframes?

Comment: The transliteration part where I have used Google transliteration takes the time.